# emacs and iPython notebook: how to see entire documentation tooltip?

Tags: python, emacs, jupyter-notebook

I've been using Emacs iPython Notebook (ein) and I love it, but for one thing: C-c C-f opens a popup/tooltip with the docstring for the object at point, which is super cool.  It cuts off after 12 lines, though, and as far as I can tell any subsequent keystroke causes it to disappear.  Does anyone know how to access the rest of the docstring?

Comment: Did you raise an issue at https://github.com/tkf/emacs-ipython-notebook/issues?

Comment: Try pressing `C-<down>` that is normal keybinding for `popup` to scroll-down, I am not sure whether this works for ein, since I do not use it.

Comment: `C-<down>` works only for auto-complete-mode sorry for the confusion

Comment: @abo-abo, yes, I did submit an issue there.

Comment: Thanks, abo-abo and Iqbal Ansari for the suggestions. I received a response to the github issue offline from one of the developers.  This is on the wishlist of fixes :)

Comment: I've been using this as a workaround: open a scratch ein notebook (M-x  ein:notebook-scratchsheet-open), and execute help(object) in a cell.  It's a little clunkier but gets the full docstring into emacs.

Answer (score 0):

Ein opens the full doc in a pager buffer if you prefix `C-c C-f` (ein:pytools-request-tooltip) with a `C-u`.

That's `C-u C-c C-f`

[ein doc](https://millejoh.github.io/emacs-ipython-notebook/)